# POST not working in HTML / PHP in certain circumstances

Tags: javascript, php, html, session

I have a complex web page that's part of a diary website used by 100+ users at a clients company.  The site is built in PHP and also incorporates HTML and JavaScript.  In that page I have a number of tabs and each tab has lots of buttons, plus other controls.  These have all worked fine for a number of years, but recently we've been finding a problem that only materialises in certain circumstances.  Basically, there is one tab in the page, where the user can set up a list of dates that need to be entered into the diary for a certain entry type.  We have popup calendars in that tab, where our users can select start and end dates for the date list.  The problem is that when that date list gets past around 180 dates, the buttons for changing the previous/next month and year just stop working.

I have tried coding this in at least 3 different ways in an attempt to resolve the problem, but I get the same problem with each alternative way that I've tried.  Also, as I see it, it makes no sense that the number of dates in the list is causing a problem, because the code simply can't know how many dates are in the list at the point with the year or month are being changed.  I will now give the key bits of code for this.

code for the popup calendar (previous year button only) this is all set up in an HTML table:

```
<td colspan='1' align='center'>
  <?php
    $prev_year = $_SESSION['popup_2_year'] - 1;
    echo "<span id='prev_year_point'><img onclick='submitPreviousYearChange(".$prev_year.")' src='../img/left.gif'></img></span>";
  ?>
</td>
```

code from the sites home page (index.php) these are just key sections taken from a much larger file.  This first bit is from near the top of the file, before any HTML, etc, are inserted.

```
if (isset($_POST["previous_year"]) && is_numeric($_POST["previous_year"]))
{
  $_SESSION['popup_2_year']--;
  $_SESSION['calendar_popup_2_show'] = true;
}
```

this next bit is from the JavaScript section in the pages HTML head section:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  <!--
    function submitPreviousYearChange(prev_year)
    {
      diary_form = document.forms['diary'];

      diary_form_element = diary_form.elements['previous_year'];
      diary_form_element.value = prev_year;

      document.diary.submit();
    }
  -->
</script>
```

finally, this bit is from towards the end of the pages body section.  This is a hidden POST variable that is used to store the 'previous_year' value.  that value is passed from the popup calendar to the JavaScript function shown above. The JavaScript function stores the year value to the hidden post variable, so that it can by used by the first bit of index.php code shown above.

```
<input type='hidden' name='previous_year' value=''>
```

As I've already said, this all works fine unless we get too many dates in the date list.  I realise it probably makes no sense, but if anyone can give me suggestions for resolving it, they would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe [post_max_size](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) in your php.ini?

Comment: Have you checked your browser console when performing above functionality... Maybe their could be an issue there in js ... Also check error logs on server... They are a great help for finding errors. Also try to increase your post data size on server... You can do it in cpanel... As told in above comment